# iOS memory leak, custom TabBar runaway allocation of view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I am using the following code to switch between two tabs:

```
-(void)switchPage:(UIButton *)sender{


    DLog(@"");
    DLog(@"child view controllers %lu", (unsigned long)self.childViewControllers.count);


    switch(sender.tag){
        case 0:{

            for(id object in self.childViewControllers){

                if([object isKindOfClass:[QuestionsVC class]]){


                    [questionsTab willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                    [questionsTab.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [questionsTab removeFromParentViewController];
                    questionsTab = nil;

                }

            }

            questionsTab = [[QuestionsVC alloc] init];
            [self addChildViewController:questionsTab];
            [self.view addSubview: questionsTab.view];
            [questionsTab didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tabBarView];
            [self drawGrayLineLayer];

            break;
        }

        case 1:{


            for(id object in self.childViewControllers){

                if([object isKindOfClass:[AnswersVC class]]){

                    [answersTab willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                    [answersTab.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [answersTab removeFromParentViewController];
                    answersTab = nil;

                }

            }

            answersTab = [[AnswersVC alloc] init];
            [self addChildViewController:answersTab];
            [self.view addSubview: answersTab.view];
            [answersTab didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tabBarView];
            [self drawGrayLineLayer];

            break;
        }

}
```

The curious thing is that the count of childVCs for the root viewcontroller (the tab bar), remains constant while none of the childviewcontrollers are released.

What is the problem?

Below is an instruments snapshot telling me that each viewcontroller gets re-allocated each time the code runs, and the old one does not get deallocated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your controller structure is. Are you implementing a custom tab bar controller - like controller? You should describe your structure, and if you're keeping an array of controllers.

Comment: I have iVars to all the childVCs... and there is one root VC, the tabbar controller, which allocates childs using the method posted above. And yes-- im implementing a custom tab bar controller. thanks!

Comment: You're looping through self.childViewControllers. Does that mean you already have several controllers as children? Do you create all the controllers you need up front, and then just switch between them (like a UITabBarController does)?

Comment: A few things could be happening with your view controllers.  1. You still have an existing pointer to the VC somewhere. Is the method you have shown the only source of creating the VCs? or 2. You have created a retain cycle in your VC, likely via referencing self inside a block. Do these view controllers use blocks? or have any other strong pointers to them?

Comment: @PatrickGoley i had a retain cycle with setting the VC as a delegate to objects it created as strong... thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was the problem for me was that I initialized other objects from the child viewcontrollers that then had a delegate property, and that delegate was `strong` so the objects retained its parent, the delegate -- the viewcontrolller, which created retain cycles.

Delegates should almost always be `weak` (or almost never `strong`) from what i have learned